# Wordpress plugin to import/embed Facebook events with comments

Tags: wordpress, facebook

Do you know any good solution (possibly a plugin) to import or embed FB events on the website along with comments/posts connected with it?

Answer (score 0):

SNAP - Has this ability https://www.nextscripts.com/snap-features/auto-import-comments-from-facebook-and-twitter/ - It work on Wordpress but it require a lot of basic reading and testing before it actually is what you want